# iText(Sharp): KeepTogether causes image to not be drawn

Tags: itext

I've got an iTextSharp application that is almost working - but in one section I have a line of text and an image, and I want to ensure that whatever else I do to the document (insert or remove text above), a page break will not be inserted between them.

If I create a paragraph and add 3 items to it:

```
1) new Chunk("Header Text")
2) new Chunk("\n")
3) new Image(...), ScaleToFit(60x100) for testing
```

The image displays properly.  But if I then set the paragraph's KeepTogether to true, the image disappears (there isn't even space left in which the image would have been drawn, it's as if I never added the image to the paragraph).

If I do the exact same thing, only the third item in the paragraph is another Chunk of text, it all works correctly.

Is this a known limitation/bug of iTextSharp?

Added later: sample code

```
Paragraph p;

Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER);

BaseFont helvetica = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
Font font = new Font(helvetica, 10.0f);

PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream("keep.pdf", FileMode.Create));
writer.StrictImageSequence = true;

doc.Open();

Image image = Image.GetInstance(new Uri("http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81cSsMiRCOL.jpg"));
image.ScaleToFit(92, 115);

doc.Add(new Chunk("Before Image, not in a paragraph\n", font));
doc.Add(image);
doc.Add(new Chunk("\nAfter Image, not in a paragraph", font));

p = new Paragraph(new Chunk("Before Image, not kept together\n", font));
p.Add(image);
p.Add(new Chunk("\nAfter Image, not kept together", font));
doc.Add(p);

p = new Paragraph(new Chunk("Before Image, Kept Together\n", font));
p.Add(image);
p.Add(new Chunk("\nAfter Image, Kept Together", font));
p.KeepTogether = true;
doc.Add(p);

doc.Close();
```

Comment: Which version of iTextSharp are you using? Maybe it's a bug that was already fixed in a more recent version.

Comment: iTextSharp.dll says version 5.5.7.0 (both "File version" and "Product version").

Comment: Can you provide some exact code that we can use to reproduce this?

Comment: I added the code, I don't know if that sends you a notification or not ...

Comment: Is there a better way to report bugs in iTextSharp?